# how to copy the elements of an array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, reverse

I tried to make a JavaScript program to reverse a string but the values of the array `b` are not going into the array `c`.

```js
var a = window.prompt("Enter a string");
var b = a.split("");

for (var i = b.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var j = 0;
  var c = [];
  c[j] = b[i];
  j++;
}

var d = c.join(",");
console.log(d);
```

Comment: `const arrClone = [...arr];`

Comment: What did you see when you stepped through the code in the debugger, setting breakpoints and examining variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable declarations for `j` and `c` must be moved outside the `for` loop, otherwise you're redefining them in every iteration:

```js
var a = prompt('Enter a string');
var b = a.split('');
var j = 0;
var c = [];

for (var i = b.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  c[j] = b[i];
  j++;
}

var d = c.join(',');

console.log(d);
```

It should be noted that this program can be extremely simplified by using the built-in [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method:

```js
var a = prompt('Enter a string');
var d = a.split('').reverse().join(',');

console.log(d);
```

Comment: The , is still coming between the words.How can i remove it?

Comment: @SanjaySajwan I'm sorry, but I feel like that should be obvious at your level. There's only three lines of code, and only one string has a comma in it.

Comment: Why not put the `j++` in the third part ("final expression") of the for loop? You could initialize `j` there too, so just `for (var i = b.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) c[j] = b[i];`, However, it might be slightly simpler to just write `var i = b.length, j = 0; while (i) c[i--] = b[j++];`.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, there are several improvements that could be made to the initial version of the program, but I decided to focus solely on the issue that was causing the code not to work. This isn't [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), after all.

Answer (score 0):

You should define variable `j` and array `c` outside the `for` loop curly braces.

```
    var a = window.prompt("Enter a string");
    var b = a.split("");
    var j=0;
    var c=[];
    for(var i=b.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        c[j]=b[i];
        j++;

    }
    var d=c.join(",");
    console.log(d);
```

Answer (score -1):

A copy can be made using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
arrayCopy = myArray.slice(0)
```